# Java map import type

Tags: java, arrays, file, vector, ascii

I am creating a game in Java, and currently I import an ASCII map (world) into a 2D array, for example:

world.txt

```
###################
#-----------------#
#-----###---------#
#-----###---------#
#-----------------#
###################
```

in Java:

```
char[][] world = new char[lines][characters_per_line];
// Import ASCII map into world[y][x] array so that world[2][6] would give: #
```

However, I am planning on creating huge maps 
(10000 by 10000 tiles, where one tile represents about 5 pixels). As these maps need to be downloaded by the game client (from the game server), it will require a lot of bandwidth.

So I thought about using bitmaps instead of ASCII maps to import, but these are also large, and would become difficult to manage as the map will get large.

**I am looking for file type which has a small file size relative to bitmaps and ASCII maps which could be used in the same context.**
(For example some vector file)

Comment: Why not giving the map to the client with the game ? and just do a verification of the `map-file` at the request of login. For example: You will send the client the map name, in a response he will send you the md5 hash and you will join or decline him. At this approach no download is needed.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but don't you think ASCII maps or bitmaps are very inefficient for this purpose? Especially when the size gets very large?

Comment: If you'll transfer your data compress then it would be fairly easy to use the current idea your using, because those are just plain files, with lots of common characters.

Comment: Always try the simple solution first. See how well the maps compress with `gzip`, and then see if just turning on `gzip` encoding on your server will be enough without needing to get invasive in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data, you might only want to transfer the places where '#' are actually placed. In addition, you can encode how many subsequent '#' are there. Example:

```
0 0 21
1 20 2
2 6 3
...
```

and so on. Read this as

1. At position 0,0 there are 21 subsequent '#' (wrapping around to next line)
2. At position 1 20 there are 2 subsequent '#'
3. At position 2 6 there are 3 '#'